# Entity Framework connection string with SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I created an Entity Framework model from a SQL Server CE 3.5 database file, the `.sdf` is in folder `E:\Programming\WcfGardenService\WcfGardenService\GardenDAO\garden.sdf`.

Connection created was

```
<add name="GardenModel2Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Garden.sdf&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

When I debug I get this error:

> InnerException
>   The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source =
>   E:\Programming\WcfGardenService\WcfGardenService\WcfGardenService\bin\Debug\Garden.sdf
>   ]"}
>   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}

I can make it work by putting the `garden.mdf` in the folder it is looking at, but why the discrepancy?

Comment: Are you talking about a mdf or a sdf here?

Comment: what part of the code the app.config? or the data access layer?